# Discord Bot cannot send messages because send is not an attribute of context

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am re implementing my commands the correct way accordingly to the documentation, using context and command decorators instead of on_message listeners, transferring my commands over is kind of a pain but the documentation has been rather helpful thankful. Unfortunately I've run into an issue which prevents me from sending messages...

Before the move, the way I would send messages was like this

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id in AdminID:
    await client.send_message(message.channel. 'message')
```

Unfortunately this does not work on the new format because there is no message argument to get information from, what you have to do is use is the ctx (context) argument instead which looks something like this according to the documentation

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

Although the bot recognizes the command and goes there, i cannot send a message because send is not an attribute of ctx, this code is taken strait out of the documentation, am I missing something? Can someone help me figure this out? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the documentation for a different version of the library than the one you're using.

You're using version `0.16`, also called the "async" branch. The documentation for that branch is [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

You're reading the documentation for the `1.0` version, also called the rewrite branch.

Your command would look something like

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx):
    if ctx.message.author.id in AdminID:
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, 'message')
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Should of have guessed it would be something like this, however on the send part, you separated each argument with a full stop instead of comma which causes it to crash, but if replaced by a comma, it works perfectly!